# Is it possible to use a path like "aaaa/{x},{y}" in JAX-RS?

Tags: jax-rs

I'd like to have something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("aaaa/{x},{y}")
public object getXY(@SomeAttribute("x") String x, @SomeAttribute("y") String y) {
...
}
```

Using @PathParam with Restlet JAX-RS extension does not work. I am wondering whether JAX-RS specification natively supports such URLS. By natively I mean that it is able to recognize and parse both x and y.

Of course, I can use a single `{xy}` parameter and split it by a comma. I am not interested, though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually REST URLs point to a resource. Your URL doesn't point to a single resource(This is my view on seeing your Url path. Please correct me if I am wrong). So you could choose your url like "\aaaa" with x and y as query parameters if it makes sense. I hope you are aware of how to retrieve the query parameters.